# Problema al importar clases en Python

Tags: python

Estoy practicando con Python y tengo este problema: al importar la clase se ejecuta automáticamente.
Este modulo se llama `empresa.py` y el otro se llama `loginempresa.py`.
El punto es que al logearme quiero que me envíe al formulario de registro de compra.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Ganaderia:
    def __init__(self, raza, color, peso, estado, dueño, precio, descuento):
        self.raza = raza
        self.color = color
        self.peso = peso
        self.dueño = dueño
        self.estado = estado
        self.precio = precio
        self.descuento = descuento

    def compra(self):
        descuento_real = self.descuento/100
        total = self.peso*self.precio
        total_descuento = total-(total * descuento_real)

        print(f"Se ha realizado la compra de un animal de raza {self.raza} por un precio de
              {total_descuento} con un descuento de {self.descuento} por {self.estado}")

    def realizar_compra():
        raza = raza_entry.get()
        color = color_entry.get()
        peso = float(peso_entry.get())
        dueño = dueño_entry.get()
        estado = estado_entry.get()
        precio = float(precio_entry.get())
        descuento = float(descuento_entry.get())

        ganado = Ganaderia(raza, color, peso, estado,
                           dueño, precio, descuento)
        ganado.compra()


root = tk.Tk()

raza_label = tk.Label(root, text="Raza:")
raza_entry = tk.Entry(root)

color_label = tk.Label(root, text="Color:")
color_entry = tk.Entry(root)

peso_label = tk.Label(root, text="Peso:")
peso_entry = tk.Entry(root)

dueño_label = tk.Label(root, text="Dueño:")
dueño_entry = tk.Entry(root)

estado_label = tk.Label(root, text="Estado del toro:")
estado_entry = tk.Entry(root)

descuento_label = tk.Label(root, text="Descuento por el estado del toro:")
descuento_entry = tk.Entry(root)

precio_label = tk.Label(root, text="Precio de compra por kilo:")
precio_entry = tk.Entry(root)

compra_button = tk.Button(
    root, text="Realizar compra", command=Ganaderia.realizar_compra)

raza_label.pack()
raza_entry.pack()

color_label.pack()
color_entry.pack()

peso_label.pack()
peso_entry.pack()

dueño_label.pack()
dueño_entry.pack()

estado_label.pack()
estado_entry.pack()

descuento_label.pack()
descuento_entry.pack()

precio_label.pack()
precio_entry.pack()

compra_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Acá está el segundo código donde hago el llamado.
Sin poner nada ya me sale el formulario de la otra clase.
Ya probé varias formas: usando `None` a la clase para que no se ejecute, pero no logro resultado.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

```
from empresa import Ganaderia
import tkinter as tk

class GanaderiaApp:
    def __init__(self, cliente, clave):
        self.cliente = cliente
        self.clave = clave

    def iniciar_sesion(self):
        if self.validar_datos():
            print("Bienvenido")

        else:
            print("Error: Datos de inicio de sesión incorrectos")

    def validar_datos(self):
        if self.cliente == "admin" and self.clave == "12345":
            return True

        else:
            print("error")


class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.cliente_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.clave_entry = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Ingresar",
                                      command=self.iniciar_sesion)

        cliente_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Usuario:")
        cliente_label.pack()
        self.cliente_entry.pack()

        clave_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Clave:")
        clave_label.pack()
        self.clave_entry.pack()

        self.login_button.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def iniciar_sesion(self):
        cliente = self.cliente_entry.get()
        clave = self.clave_entry.get()
        ganaderia_app = GanaderiaApp(cliente, clave)
        ganaderia_app.iniciar_sesion()


login = Login()
```

Acá muestro la ejecución, me sale directo el formulario de `empresa.py`, sin logearme:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando importas, Python *ejecuta* el código importado. Si tienes instrucciones sueltas en el primer nivel, las va a ejecutar. La solución es que pongas todo el código en funciones; así puedes importar "sin ejecutar" nada. Luego llamas la función que deseas. Ojo, que el "def" es algo ejecutable, cuyo resultado es agregar una función al programa.

Comment: No está relacionado con tu pregunta pero diría que al pulsar en tu botón `compra_button` recibirás una excepción porque la función `Ganaderia.realizar_compra` recibirá un argumento (la clase `Ganaderia`) pero espera recibir 0 argumentos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace que se abra esa ventana son las líneas `root = tk.Tk()` y siguientes de `empresa.py`.
Así es como funciona Python.
Las palabras reservadas `def` y `class` añaden símbolos a tu módulo.
Por lo tanto Python al importar el archivo debe ejecutarlo.
Si tienes código en tu archivo `empresa.py` que no quieres que se ejecute al importarlo, debes introducir ese código en una función que por convención llamamos `main`.
Con este cambio evitas que se ejecute al importar el archivo.
Si además quieres que `main` se ejecute cuando lances el código desde `empresa.py`, deberás escribir: `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`.